# unable to upload with presigned url on aws s3 with java sdk

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I receive a presigned URL to upload to S3 .  When i upload given the code below, i am getting a 403 status response.  I tried setting the bucket policy to public on the web console but that has not solved the issue.  Any other insights on how to fix the issue? i have also tried adding the ACL to PublicREADWRITE.

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setRequestMethod("PUT");

    OutputStream out = connection.getOutputStream();

   // OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
    //out.write("This text uploaded as an object via presigned URL.");


    byte[] boundaryBytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(edmFile));
    out.write(boundaryBytes);
    out.close();

    // Check the HTTP response code. To complete the upload and make the object available,
    // you must interact with the connection object in some way.
    int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("HTTP response code: " + responseCode);
```

Presigned url:

```
  private URL getUrl(String bucketName, String objectKey) {

        String clientRegion = "us-east-1";
        java.util.Date expiration = new java.util.Date();
        long expTimeMillis = expiration.getTime();
        expTimeMillis += 1000 * 60 * 10;
        expiration.setTime(expTimeMillis);

        AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                .withCredentials(new ProfileCredentialsProvider())
                .withRegion(clientRegion)
                .build();
        GeneratePresignedUrlRequest generatePresignedUrlRequest =
                new GeneratePresignedUrlRequest(bucketName, objectKey)
                        .withMethod(HttpMethod.GET)
                        .withExpiration(expiration);
        URL url = s3Client.generatePresignedUrl(generatePresignedUrlRequest);

        System.out.println("Pre-Signed URL: " + url.toString());
        return url;
    }
```

Comment: Add the code you are using to generate the presigned url.

Comment: added @cementblocks

Comment: @alihaider your pre-signed Url is created with `.withMethod(HttpMethod.GET)` and you are trying to perform PUT upload operation. Is that the cause?. I think they have to be in sync.

Comment: @Imran if you add it as an answer, I will accept it - thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed, signed Url should exactly match on what you want to do next.

Your pre-signed Url is created with `GET` operation, that's why upload `PUT` operation is failing with access denied error.

Try updating the withMethod to PUT.

```
GeneratePresignedUrlRequest generatePresignedUrlRequest =
                new GeneratePresignedUrlRequest(bucketName, objectKey)
                        .withMethod(HttpMethod.PUT)
                        .withExpiration(expiration);
```